# Xcode won't display README when viewing a Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I converted an iOS framework project to a Swift Package.

Everything went smoothly and I can find and add the package to other projects. But Xcode won't display the README for the project. It only displays, "Unable to load the Read Me."

I've stripped the README down to just a header and one line of text.

I've removed the couple of extra files from the project that exist at the root level.

But I still just get the same message.

The project is located at: https://github.com/ecrichlow/IoGInfrastructure-iOS.git

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error - no package's README displayed and when I was adding the package it complained that package resolution failed.

Updating swift-tools, by updating Xcode helped.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode – at least up to Version 15.1 (15C65) – won't display README for Swift Packages on **PRIVATE** repos.

It's really as simple and dumb as that.

While the package manager finds and loads your package just fine from private repos, the element displaying the repo operates under the assumption that the README can be read without authentication.

As the package information is read correctly, this is a bug on Apple's side.